# Facebook Fangate with rest-graph gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook

A fangate is a method to check if user likes the page where the app is, if so, he can view the content.

I've been trying for a while to do a fangate with rest-graph gem.

```
rest_graph_setup(
  :write_session => true,
  :iframe => true,
  :auto_authorize => true,
  :auto_authorize_scope => 'email',
  :app_id        => ENV['FB_ID'],
  :secret        => ENV['FB_SC'],
  :write_cookies => true,
)
raise rest_graph.get('me/likes/PAGE_ID').inspect
```

Thats the way I connect to the app and get, in theory, the status (/USER_ID/likes/PAGE_ID). But nothing happens, I got an empty array for a PAGE_ID I liked.

I also tried fql method

```
raise rest_graph.fql('SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id=PAGE_ID AND uid=USER_ID').inspect
```

But again, I get an empty array.

So, any ideas for this?

Comment: I'm working on a fangate as we speak, but I seem to have a little problem getting the data. On my own page it works (I guess since the app already has access to my likes). So in order to make this work should I first let my users authorize with my app? Followed by a "like-check" and after those I can display my hidden content?

Comment: Nevermind solved by: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5329818/seamless-way-to-check-if-user-likes-page/5331541#5331541

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you don't have the `user_likes` permission in the scope. Add it like

```
rest_graph_setup(
  :write_session => true,
  :iframe => true,
  :auto_authorize => true,
  :auto_authorize_scope => 'email,user_likes',
  :app_id        => ENV['FB_ID'],
  :secret        => ENV['FB_SC'],
  :write_cookies => true,
)
raise rest_graph.get('me/likes/PAGE_ID').inspect
```

And that will probably solve your issue

Comment: Worked like a charm. Now I got the problem that Facebook doesn't update instantly the db and I got like a 4 minute delay. Thanks Jeduan.